# Mathematically checking if a number is positive, negative or 0

Tags: java, math

A sprite in a game wants to walk toward a given `(x, y)` coordinate pair but can only move `walkSpeed` pixels per tick.

To figure out how far to move them, I've just got a block of `if` statements.

```
public void walkToward(Integer x, Integer y) {
    int walkSpeed = 1;

    int dX = x - getxPos();
    int dY = y - getyPos();

    int moveX, moveY;


    if (dX > 0) {
        moveX = walkSpeed;
    } else if (dX < 0) {
        moveX = -walkSpeed;
    } else {
        moveX = 0;
    }

    if (dY > 0) {
        moveY = walkSpeed;
    } else if (dY < 0) {
        moveY = -walkSpeed;
    } else {
        moveY = 0;
    }

    {code to move player ...}
}
```

This isn't a problem, but I feel like there would be some more mathematical way to do it. Something of the form

```
int moveX = {some operation} * walkSpeed;
```

Where `{some operation}` turns all positive numbers to 1, all negative numbers to -1 and 0 to 0.

Comment: There's Math.signum, but it accepts a double and returns a double.

Comment: look at `Math.signum`

Comment: So something like `moveX = (int) Math.signum((float) dX)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use [Math.signum()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#signum%28double%29)

> Returns the signum function of the argument; zero if the argument is
>   zero, 1.0 if the argument is greater than zero, -1.0 if the argument
>   is less than zero.

Comment: I just had a bit of a read about `Math.signum()` and found `Integer.signum()` which reads to be like it does the same thing but for integers. Is that right? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#signum%28int%29

Answer (score 3):

```
int moveX = Math.signum(dX);
int moveY = Math.signum(dY);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could say

`if(dX == 0){
moveX=0;}
else {moveX =dX/Math.abs(dX)*walkSpeed; }`

using dX/Math.abs(dX) will allow you to lessen your if's and conditions

Answer (score -1):

You have problem because your speed definition is not correct. It must be `sqroot(dX*dX + dY*dY)`. So sign doesn't matter.

Java solution : `Math.hypot(dX, dY)`

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, though it is good feedback on my example. Would be better as a comment I think.